# Изменение конструктора Item'a в ItemsControl WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, .net

Доброго времени суток всем!

На форме имеется ItemsControl. В конструкторе каждого item'a лежит ComboBox, в котором пользователь выбирает необходимую ему команду.

Вопрос заключается в том, как определить дальнейшее построение item'a.
Например пользователь выбрал "Наличие..." и далее должен появиться ComboBox с выбором номера ТС и ComboBox c выбором типа. Далее если пользователь в типе выбирает "Получить" ничего больше на форме не должно появляться, а если в типе выбрал "Установить" то должно появиться поле для ввода значения.

Был бы рад если бы поделились информацией или ссылками на реализацию подобных конструкций. Интересует как настройка интерфейса, так и настройка самого класса item, которого создается.

Пример кода:

```
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Border Width="350"
                            Height="200"
                            Background="DarkRed"
                            BorderBrush="White"
                            BorderThickness="2"
                            CornerRadius="5"
                            Margin="0,5,0,0">
                        <Grid>
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"></ColumnDefinition>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"></ColumnDefinition>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"></ColumnDefinition>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="auto"></RowDefinition>
                                <RowDefinition Height="auto"></RowDefinition>
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                            <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=CommandNameList}"
                                      SelectedIndex="{Binding Path=CommandNameSelected}"></ComboBox>

                        </Grid>
                    </Border>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
```

Пример:
[image: То как выглядит сейчас, это предварительная версия без стилей и тд.]
Спасибо за помощь!

Comment: В конструкторе лежит `ComboBox`? Это как? приведите код

Comment: А еще добавьте картинку с изображением того что вы хотите получить, пока ничего не понятно

Comment: Ага, только это не конструктор, а шаблон элемента

Comment: @Андрей да, шаблон. Ошибся.

Comment: @Андрей добавил картинку, на этом пока застрял.
Пока вижу только один вариант, создать универсальный шаблон, а в теле класса добавить поля для отображени(hidden, collapsedm, visible) и при выборе определенного варианта включать или отключать нужное.

Comment: Во втором ComboBox у вас 2 значения? Получить/Установить, так?

Comment: @Андрей для каждого из выбранных вариантов свое.
У нас сейчас 69 названий. В зависимости от выбранного варианта в первом случае добавляется combobox следующий (в большинстве случаев во втором combobox'e выбирается номер ТС, но есть исключения).

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/63483/discussion-between--and-uporotayapanda).

Comment: @Андрей благодарю за помощь!
Но за пол часа PM решил, что все должно быть по другому и дизайн интерфейса будет совершенно другим.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
  <DataTemplate>
    <Border Padding="10" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1">
      <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
          <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
          <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
          <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
          <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <ComboBox Name="f_Root">
          <ComboBox.Items>
            <System:String>Наличие...</System:String>
            <System:String>Получить</System:String>
            <System:String>Установить</System:String>
          </ComboBox.Items>
        </ComboBox>
        <ComboBox Name="f_TS" Grid.Row="1" Visibility="Hidden"/>
        <ComboBox Name="f_Type" Grid.Row="2" Visibility="Hidden"/>
        <TextBox Name="f_Value" Grid.Row="3" Visibility="Hidden"/>
      </Grid>
    </Border>
    <DataTemplate.Triggers>
      <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=SelectedItem, ElementName=f_Root}" Value="Наличие...">
        <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" TargetName="f_TS"/>
        <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" TargetName="f_Type"/>
      </DataTrigger>
      <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=SelectedItem, ElementName=f_Root}" Value="Установить">
        <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" TargetName="f_Value"/>
      </DataTrigger>
    </DataTemplate.Triggers>
  </DataTemplate>
</ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
```

Думаю установить элементы f_TS и f_Type Вы сможете =)

ДА! Совсем забыл!

Подключите в контроле

```
xmlns:System="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
```

Comment: Спасибо! Хорошая реализация!
В будущих проектах постараюсь самостоятельно реализовать!